# sed command: bad flag in substitute command: '/'

Tags: bash, sed

I am having challenges formatting some files. I want to delete everything between the [&lnP until the [&R] in the file1.trees and then create a new file called file1_edit.trees. But I am getting the error 'bad flag in substitute command: '/''

```
    sed -i '' 's/[&lnP/,/[&R]/{//!d;}/g' file1.trees > file1_edit.trees 


    Error --->> sed: 1: "s/[&lnP/,/[&R]/{//!d;}/g": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

Comment: escape square brackets, remove rediection as you are doing inplace updates.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you means `sed 's/[&lnP\/,/[&R]/{\/!d;}/g'`

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve - could you [edit] to add a (small) sample input and expected output?  As it is, I can't tell whether you're trying to `s` (substitute) within a line or to `d` (delete) a range of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace "[&lnP/,/[&R]" with "{//!d;}", your command should be:

```
sed 's/\[&lnP\/,\/\[&R\]/{\/\/!d;}/g' file1.trees > file1_edit.trees
```

You would need to escape characters which would get confused with search/replace part by having forward slash. Also escape characters which would be treated as a special characters in regex (meta characters).

Also remove -i flag which would do the changes inplace into the file.